# Azure local storage emulator exception - Null InputStream is not a valid argument

Tags: azure

Im using windows azure with java over tomcat. I want to use the local storage emulator. so I started the local stoage emulator and use:

storageConnectionString = "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"

then im trying to create a table:

```
public static void createUsersTable() {
    try {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount
                .parse(storageConnectionString);

        CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount
                .createCloudTableClient();

        CloudTable table = tableClient.getTableReference("users");

        table.createIfNotExist();

        Logger.info("table users was created");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.info("table users cannot be created");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but when excecuting the line table.createIfNotExist(), im getting the exception:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null InputStream is not a valid argument
    at com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.createSR(WstxInputFactory.java:614)
    at com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(WstxInputFactory.java:317)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.core.storage.utils.Utility.createXMLStreamReaderFromStream(Utility.java:327)
    at

I cant find anything over the internet on that exception, does anyone saw this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found what the problem was. Im using maven and I didnt put the azure dependencies over there, just used the jar file. this caused collision with some axis jar imported by maven.

Comment: can you give exact clarification? i am facing the same issue